# AngularJS doesn't update ng-model after jQuery event on Django admin date widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, django-admin

In my current project I'm using this [calendar.js](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-admin/source/browse/branches/appengine_admin_forms/appengine_admin/media/js/calendar.js?r=78) javascript library together AngularJS.

I'm bind calendar.js widget and AngularJS ng-model to my input field in this way:

```
<input class="vDateField" type="text" ng-model="date" ng-init="date='{{ form.date.value | default_if_none:"" }}'"
```

vDateField is the class that bing calendars and {{ }} are backend template engine tags.

My problem is when I select the date with calendarjs picker, my input fied is updated but ng-model "date" doesn't.

Is there any solutions without modify calendarjs widget??

Here the rendered input tag:

```
<div>
     <label class="required" for="id_date">Data contratto</label>
     <input class="vDateField ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" type="text" ng-model="date" ng-init="date=''" name="date" placeholder="02/02/2015">
     <span class="datetimeshortcuts">&nbsp;<a href="javascript:DateTimeShortcuts.handleCalendarQuickLink(0, 0);">Oggi</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="javascript:DateTimeShortcuts.openCalendar(0);" id="calendarlink0"><img src="/static/admin/img/icon_calendar.gif" alt="Calendario"></a></span>
</div>
```

Here the javascript sources of the picker. DateTimeShortCuts.js contains the code for display mini link to setup current date time to my input field and a mini calendar icon to open up calendar widget.

I register the widget by adding class="vDateField" to my input tag as shown below.

[DateTimeShortCuts.js](http://pastebin.com/mbvf964F)

[calendar.js](http://pastebin.com/MeXVqRBr)

Comment: Of course you need to trigger a digest cycle when form.date.value changes because it is not an angular module.

Answer (score 2):

Had this same problem, solved it like this (example with jquery datepicker)

```
$('#myDateInput').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            onSelect: function (dateText) {
                updateDate(dateText);
            },
            onClose: function (dateText) {
                updateDate(dateText);
            }
        });

function updateDate(dateText) {

        var date = angular.element('#myDateInput').val();
        angular.element('#myDateInput').val(date);
        if (dateText) {
            $scope.object.date = dateText;
        }
        $scope.object.dateReadable = date;
        $scope.safeApply(function (childScope) { });

}

// safely apply changes to the $scope
$scope.safeApply = function (fn) {
    var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
    if (phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
        if (fn && (typeof (fn) === 'function')) {
            fn();
        }
    } else {
        this.$apply(fn);
    }
};
```

Set date on page load

```
$("#myDateInput").datepicker("setDate", $scope.dateReadable);
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="date" class="control-label">Date:</label>
        <input type="date" name="date" id="myDateInput" class="form-control" />
    </div>
```

The important thing here is that I use SafeApply to apply the changes to the $scope. Hope the example helps even tough it's a working sample for me.

Why do I have to do this? Well angular isn't aware of what happens outside its $scope, in this case jQUery. So we will have to tell it manually.

EDIT:
It might be a bit confusing with date and dateReadable but ignore the details and look at the safeApply that binds the changes to the $scope.

Comment: It seems a complex solution... :( 
How can I adapt your solution to my problem?

Comment: It's difficult to do a "working" example without knowing anything more than what you've written. The takeaway is, Use the safeApply method after you've manually set the date on your $scope object. You trigger this by onSelect and onClose.

Comment: Sorry, I've added the rendered input tag from browser dev tools...
Can this help you? Thanks.

Comment: @FabrizioA Hmm, what part of my example is confusing so I can clarify?

Comment: In my page, I will have a lot of date picker and client side logic. I'll have to set all your javascript blocks and hidden fields for any datepicker in my app? :(
Do you advice me if is better to use pure angularJS date picker?
Do you advice me if is better to develop an entire AngularJS / Rest API stack (without bind with Django backend forms)?

Comment: @FabrizioA I think you can use jQuery datepicker. You don't need an extra input field, that's only for the example. The important thing is in this case to always use safeApply after you've updated the $scope.date value.

Comment: Return to my code... I've only setup vDateField class to my input field to load and bind calendar.js widget, so, do I need to modify that library to set onSelect:OnClose handlers? You say: "always use safeApply after you've updated the $scope.date value" .. my problem is that $scope.date must be updated after I have selected the date from calendar.js widget. Sorry for my english...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70787/discussion-between-andreas-and-fabrizio-a).

Comment: I've added the javascript sources of my datepicker. I would like to figure out how to register a callback to call $scope.$apply()

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful if you ask your question in more detail. However have you tried ng-init="date='{{ form.date.value | default_if_none:"" }}'" before input element?

Comment: If I select a date with calendarjs picker the input field will be updated but the event for updating ng-model date isn't triggered.... if I add a single character after a date inside input field then ng-model date will be updated.
I used ng-init="date='{{ form.date.value | default_if_none:"" }}'" to set the initial value of $scope.date when I load the form from server.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved with this directive and by set $('widget_element').trigger('change') on a callback function of 3d-part widget.

In this case, the widget is default Django Admin date widget.

```
contract_form_app.directive('vDateField', [function() {
return {
    require: "ngModel",
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        element.addClass("vDateField");
        var updateModel = function (dateText) {
            scope.$apply(function () {
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);
            });
        };
        django.jQuery('input').on('change', function() {
            updateModel(element.val());
        });
    }
};
}]);
```